# Uses of unary or sparse languages in other models

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

In the turing model we have the statements that if there is an unary or sparse language that is NP complete then P=NP and if there is a Turing reduction from an NP complete problem to an unary or sparse language then NP is in P/poly.

Is there an analog of these statements in the Valiant model and in the BSS model?